# The direct image of a fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $X,Y_1,Y_2$ be algebraic varieties. Let $p:Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ be a fiber bundle with fiber isomorphic to $\mathbf P_1^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $s_i: Y_i \rightarrow X$, $i=1,2,$ be surjective morphisms. Moreover, $s_1 = s_2 \circ p$. Let $\mathcal E$ be a local system on $X$. Then is it true that $Rp_* s_1^{-1} \mathcal E \simeq H^{\bullet} (\mathbf{P}_1^n) \otimes s_2^{-1} \mathcal E$? What about when the fiber $\mathbf P_1^n$ is replaced by arbitrary spaces?  If it is true, please tell me how to prove it, or where can I find a proof for it.

If you think this is just too basic, please assume only the knowledge about the definition of the concepts.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: What is $H^\bullet$ here? It seems you have a complex of sheaves on one side of your isomorphism, and a single sheaf on the other side (I'm guessing $H^\bullet$ means...cohomology...algebra)?

Comment: @AlexYoucis:Thank you very much for pointing out this confusing part in my question. Yes, $H^{\bullet}$ is the cohomology. The left-hand-side is a complex because $Rp_*$ is a right derived functor, and the right-hand-side is also a complex because $H^{\bullet}(\mathbf P_1^n)$ is a complex.